# Automatically resize code blocks to fit the horizontal scroll bar within the screen

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

Consider a fairly large block of code. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42959113/8387076). On my 1366x768 screen laptop, this is what I see:

[image]

If I have to scroll horizontally in the code block, I have to first scroll down, scroll horizontally within the code block, and scroll up to return to the line I was reading.

This is okay for smaller code blocks, but for larger ones, I have to again find the line that I was reading. This is becoming a headache when I am continuously going through codes on the site.

**Why can't the size of the code block be changed automatically according to the screen width so that the horizontal scrollbar is available without having to scroll?**

Consider a different site, [physicsforums.com](https://www.physicsforums.com). They use different software, but they have nicely implemented the option to automatically resize the code blocks to fit within the screen. I do not have to scroll down in order to scroll horizontally.

[image]

Can something similar be implemented here?

Answer (score 4):

The fix would be as simple as setting a variable max height instead of currently fixing it at 600px.

E.g.:

```
.post-text pre, .wmd-preview pre {
    max-height: 80vh;
}
```

I've added this to my [ReduceClutter userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReduceClutter.user.js).

Comment: How do I implement this in my browser?

Comment: You'll need to install a userscript manager first (https://www.tampermonkey.net), then click on the "Raw" link on the userscript in Github. The userscript manager will prompt you to install.

Comment: If you are new to userscripts, may I also recommend [Advanced Search Helper](https://stackapps.com/q/7971) and [Sticky Post Headers & Question Table of Contents](https://stackapps.com/q/7994)

Comment: That works great! Thanks. However, I still want StackOverflow to make this a default feature of their site.